# Lubuntu Audio not working on heaphones

Tags: lubuntu, headphones, audio-jack

I recently installed Lubuntu for speed, but on Youtube, Audio isn't working. I tried the [suggested](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1473769) alsamixer, but I don't see anything muted but the mic (I have a one wire headphone. I read the mic only works on phones. can linux defy that? :o) muted, which gives a wierd sound as if I'm whatching an unknown TV channel. Here's some photos of what it looks like.

First I entered the command and got this menu:

[image]

I press F6 to then get this image:

[image]

I select Intel PCH because the other ones don't show anything. Under Intel PCH is everything: i.imgur.com/gs0azwm.png
(Don't have enough rep for more than 2 links)
So I can't raise the volume on the headphone section, but when I turn it off I hear a little puff in my headset. What is the matter? The headphones work perfectly fine on my phone, but Linux isn't picking it up.

Answer (score 1):

Install "gnome-alsamixer”(without quotes) from Synaptic Package Manager.
Then run gnome-alsamixer in terminal.
A graphical interface will open up. Check the box that reads 'Stereo Mix' (at the bottom). Now the sound will be enabled on both the speaker and the headphones. Finally, mute the speaker.

Comment: This worked for me on Lubuntu 14, but I had to check the box that reads 'HP/Speaker Auto Detect'